# Google Drive API - Search all files inside a root folder and sub folders in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to search all files inside a root folder and its sub folders in Google Drive API using C#.
Suppose there is a root folder `"A"` which contains 5 files 
and a sub folder named `"B"`.
The sub folder `"B"` contains 4 files only.
Now I have to populate all the files inside the root folder(5 + 4 = 9 files).
Currently I'm populating files like-

```
FilesResource.ListRequest list = service.Files.List();
 list.OrderBy = "createdDate";
                list.MaxResults = 1000;
if (search != null)
                {
                    list.Q = search;
                }
  FileList filesFeed = list.Execute();
```

If anyone has any idea please share.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem specifically are you having

Comment: What is search?  list will automatically return all the files and folders on drive.   Are you trying to say you just want the files and not the directories?

Comment: @ DaImTo... correct. I just need to return all the files not the directories with all file properties.

Answer (score 1):

I only have objective-C sample code for search all file and folder.

I use recursive way for search all file.

you can use file MIMEType for determine folder or file.